# Couldn't complete the moodle installation in IIS8. Script files not loaded in the main admin configuration page

Tags: php, iis, moodle, iis-8

I downloaded Moodle (MOODLE_38_STABLE) from their downloads page. 
Followed the installation instructions. During instruction it met all the requirements and allowed the further installation.

But when it reached the below page i found the theme was not loaded in the page. so now i'm not able to proceed further.

[image]

I tried providing access to all the necessary folders. 
PHP Version - 7.1.32
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The theme is cached in the dataroot folder.

Maybe check the permissions for the dataroot folder - this will be in `config.php`

```
$CFG->dataroot = 'yourdatafolder';
```

The `dataroot` folder should be a separate folder from the `wwwroot` folder.

On linux, the folder needs `02777` or `0777` permission and is accessible by the web user.

See https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_the_.28moodledata.29_data_directory

If that doesn't work, have you tried a different browser?

You could also try purge the caches, from the command line use:

```
php admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

Or as a last resort, recreate the data root folder and recreate the database then do a command line install

```
php admin/cli/install_database.php
```